# Undefined structures and functions from WinInet import

Tags: winapi, d, wininet

I'm making my first steps with D, and as a trial I am trying to access a SOAP API via the Internet. I have a working C++ app (Visual Studio 2019, Windows 10) which uses the `wininet` library. I am using Visual D within Visual Studio.

Unfortunately I am falling at the very first hurdle.

```
module Win32D;

import std.stdio;
import core.sys.windows.windows;
import core.sys.windows.wininet;

int main()
{
    HINTERNET hNet = InternetOpenA("XYZ", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler (DMD) fails to recognize the wininet types (eg HINTERNET) or functions (eg InternetOpenA). If I go to the definitions in wininet.d I can see all the prototypes.

The D tutorial suggests: "The import statement makes all public functions and types from the given module available."

I am guessing the answer is a one-liner, so I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: is it actually the compiler failing to recognize the types or is the linker failing? InternetOpenA and wininet works fine for me, but I'm also linking with wininet, e.g. see https://github.com/Pure-D/serve-d/blob/f1836f76a73d4517d82e0307329b550a3eae2c74/http/source/served/http.d#L18 and lines 41 and following

Comment: If you're seeing "Symbol Undefined" or "unresolved external symbol", it's a linker error, not a compiler error. Then you need to link with wininet.lib. That's what I get when I try your code without linking, and only for the function (since HINTERNET is not a symbol for the linker to care about). The compiler sees the symbols just fine.

Comment: @MichaelParker I think I am getting blind-sided by the Visual D implementation on Visual Studio, as it appears the errors are coming from the Intellisense, not the build. If I filter the output for just 'Build', then I clearly see tell-tale linker errors of the kind you describe. Adding wininet.lib to the linked libraries does the trick as you would expect.

Comment: @WebFreak001 Many thanks for the link. I've solved the build issue, but your sample is a great help for converting my C++ Win32 types into D.